# Pygments for Google App Engine Python Doesn't Work

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pygments

This is my code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
import pygments
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
```

But I get:

```
import pygments
ImportError: No module named pygments
INFO     2012-07-20 07:05:44,386 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

What am I doing wrong?

Does Google App Engine not support pygments? I thought it did... Could someone please correct me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run Pygments because it's pure Python, but it's not included as a default library in GAE. Instead, you need to download the source and copy it into your project.

1. Go to PyPi and download [Pygments](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pygments).
2. Unzip it, then copy the source into the app engine folder *for your project* (probably best at the top-level).
3. Then you can just do `import pygments` as usual.  If you want to put it in a subdirectory (say `mypackages`), you have to change the import string, e.g. `from mypackages import pygments`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I would up vote, but I don't have enough reputation :\

Answer (score 1):

It *supports* it (since Pygments is pure Python), but it probably doesn't *include* it. Copy the module to one of the directories in `sys.path`.

Comment: Sorry, but how would I do this?

Comment: First you download it. Then you extract it. Then you copy it.

Answer (score 0):

Move 3rd parties to `lib` directory.
Add this lines to your main file. Use `pygments` with `import pygments`

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'lib'))
import application
```

https://github.com/kamalgill/flask-appengine-template/blob/master/src/run.py